# what are the leftovers from the previous builds of Qt?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, qt, cross-compilation

it's been a while that I am trying to cross compile Qt for my Raspberry pi 4 on a lite version of OS (that has no desktop, no x server ..) on my Ubuntu 18.04

I tried many times and I changed the configuration every time and I installed other libraries on my raspberry pi but it couldn't work.. So I said maybe it is because that I have some leftovers from previous builds that make the compilation fail

for example if this is the message that I got after the configuration:

```
Qt will be installed into '/opt/rpi/qt5pi//usr/local/Qt-rasp4-5.14.2'.
Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

removing these directories and creating new empty ones `/opt/rpi/qt5pi/` and `/usr/local/Qt-rasp4-5.14.2` will solve the problem or what should I do ? ..

I has been a while since I am trying to cross compile Qt .. please if you could help don't hesitate ..